# display firebase image in gallery zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, database, firebase, zooming

so I made a gallery from my firebase database. The images are from my canvas element where your mouse draws a line. However, my canvas is large (as it is a horizontal scroll), about 16000 pixels wide, so when the images display, the strokes in the images are tiny, almost unnoticable. How could I display them larger, or say only display part of the image but zoomed in?

This is how I display the images

```
let elements = document.getElementById("gallery");

    db.collection("users")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot =>{
        //querySnapshot is all the data from the collection
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            let name=doc.id;
            //construct the div to present data in html
            let singlePerson= document.createElement("div");
            singlePerson.className="person";
            let info= document.createElement("p");
            info.innerText="Name:"+name;
            singlePerson.append(info);

            // retrieve data from storage by passing the path name of the image
            storageRef
            .child("images/"+name) //name
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(function(url){
                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src =url;

                // singlePerson.append(img);
                gallery.append(img);
                 img.style.width="100%" ;
                 img.style.height="100%" ;
           
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

update: I used img.style.clipPath to make it work!